# i want to convert a dataset of a SDF database to obseravable collection  in WPF  

Tags: c#, wpf, database, dataset, observablecollection

i am currently working with SQL CE & WPF . in the middle of coding i struck with no idea of converting  the dataset of a Database  to my observablecollection which is binds to the UI Controllers like  Listbox and listview.

plz guide me , if possible with code !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your DataSet contains a Table named Person and that Person has columns Id, Name, and Age.

You first create a `Person` class to hold your Person data:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then you use LINQ to populate your ObservableCollection:

```
var people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(
    dataset.Tables["Person"].AsEnumerable().Select(p => new Person
    {
        Id = p.Field<int>("Id"),
        Name = p.Field<string>("Name"),
        Age = p.Field<int>("Age")
    }));
```

You will need to add the following assembly reference to your project in order to use the `AsEnumerable<T>()` and `Field<T>()` extension methods:

System.Data.DataSetExtensions (in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll)

**Edit**

In response to your comment, you would normally process each change you make to the data immediately rather than try to convert the whole ObservableCollection back to the DataSet. So, for example, if you add a new Person to your ObservableCollection, you would also want to add that Person to the DataSet.

Add a person:

```
var table = dataSet.Tables["Person"];
var row = table.NewRow();
row["Id"] = person.Id;
row["Name"] = person.Name;
row["Age"] = person.Age;
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Delete a person:

```
var table = dataSet.Tables["Person"];
var row = table.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Id == person.Id);
row.Delete();
```

Update a person (say you want to change the age to 37):

```
var table = dataSet.Tables["Person"];
var row = table.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Id == person.Id);
var row["Age"] = 37;
```

---

You might also want to look into [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) because it automates a lot of this stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much .  i am extremely happy that i found some solution.  If you dont mind , please provide me the converting observable collections back to Dataset .  With same example .  So that i can use Dataset for retrieving and updating values from Database. this is waht i mean to do in my project.

Comment: M   , Thank you very much  . i taken your coding and working on this . thanks for replying with much  needed elaborated coding .

Comment: i found there is a slight mistype in the  code   at  obserabale collection   its   .... dataset.Tables("Person").AsEnumerable().Select ...  i think itis dataset.Tables["Person"].AsEnumerable()......

Comment: @Panindra, you're right (I typed the code without an editor)...I'll fix my answer. Made a couple other minor fixes too.